# I have a some scritps is working but not work in crontab

Tags: sh

I have a some scripts and, when ı was run manually the scripts were run. But
When working in crontab, the format is incorrect.

This is for a new Linux server

```
awk 'BEGIN{
FS="-"
print  "<HTML>""<table border="1" border="3" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" bgcolor=lightblue><TH>Firma</TH><TH>Charged Party No</TH><TH>Pcom Status</TH>"
}
{
printf "<TR>"
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
printf "<TD>%s</TD>",$i
print "</TR>"
}
END{
print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
}
' /app/ovocontrol/cp_not_found2.txt > file.html
sed -i "s/failure/<font color="red">failure<\/font>/g;s/success/<font color="green">success<\/font>/g" file.html
(
echo "To: **********"
echo "Subject: Son 10 Dakikaya ait Toplu SMS CUDB Hata Detayi"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo
cat file.html
echo
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

I have a some scripts and, when ı was run manually the scripts were run. But
When working in crontab, the format is incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by "the format is incorrect"?  Are you including all of the above text directly in your crontab?  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem other way , "awk '!seen[$0]++'" command incorrect my format. the code was actually a short portion of the code. I think crontab has a special settings.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a shebang, nor do you have a complete crontab, so I'm guessing at what you're actually doing.  I suspect you are trying to call those multiple commands directly from your crontab, which is a terrible idea.  Instead, put your multiple calls into a single script and invoke it from cron.  eg, do something like:

```
$ cat > /path/to/script << 'EOF'
#!/bin/sh

: ${f:=/app/ovocontrol/cp_not_found2.txt}

{
echo "To: **********"
echo "Subject: Son 10 Dakikaya ait Toplu SMS CUDB Hata Detayi"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo
printf '<HTML><table border="1" border="3" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4"'
printf ' bgcolor=lightblue><TH>Firma</TH><TH>Charged Party No</TH><TH>Pcom Status</TH>\n'
awk -F - ' {
        printf "<TR>"
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "<TD>%s</TD>",$i
        print "</TR>"
}
' "$f"
printf '</TABLE></BODY></HTML>\n'
} \
| sed -e 's@failure@<font color="red">failure</font>@g' \
      -e 's@success@<font color="green">success</font>@g'
| /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
EOF
$ chmod +x /path/to/script
$ printf 'i\n0 * * * * /path/to/script\n.\nw\nq\n' | EDITOR=ed crontab -e
```

Note that the last command above is not really a great idea, just an attempt to codify the directive to add /path/to/script to your crontab.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attention. I solved problem other way , "awk '!seen[$0]++'" command  incorrect my format. the code was actually a short portion of the code. I think maybe  crontab has a special settings. Thank you.